# What does sched_priority in struct sched_param refer to?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler

im having some hard time understanding the sched_priority role in the setscheduler func. 
Im using linux 2.4.X, and the documentation says :

```
Valid priorities for SCHED_OTHER is 0, Valid priorities for SCHED_RR\FIFO are 1...MAX_USER_RT_PRIO-1
```

But, I remember that priorities for rt procsses are 0-99, and for SCHED_OTHER 100-139, so... what did I miss ? what `sched_priority` in `struct sched_param` refers to?

Answer (score 2):

`SCHED_OTHER` is the default scheduling policy with round robin. This is has no choice of priority.

`SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` are real time scheduling policies for which the priority range from 1 to 99.

`SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE` are normal scheduling policies.

From Linux 3.14 onwards, you will find `SCHED_DEADLINE` that in which the task with earliest deadline is executed first.

You can use the `sched_priority` to set the thread priority. sched_priority is a member of the structure  `struct sched_param`.

Try out `chrt -m` to check the min/max valid priorities that can be configured/set. `chrt` can be used to set or retrieve scheduling attributes of processes.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the user space interface with the internal kernel implementation.
sched_priority is just the requested fixed real time priority. 
A task scheduled under the SCHED_OTHER policy also has a nice level.

The scale you remember is the kernel internal representation of the relative priority of a task, aggregating real time tasks and SCHED_OTHER tasks with their respective nice levels.